# Privilege Identity Management for CSP subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have been struggling to find out what way to best manage access and allowing our techs to access our customers subscriptions and Azure resources, without giving them explicit rights as contributors or the likes on each subscription.

Now I bumped into the Privilege Identity Management feature (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-privileged-identity-management-configure?toc=%2fazure%2factive-directory%2fprivileged-identity-management%2ftoc.json) and it seems like it would do exactly what I want. Just-in-time administrative access for example.

Now with how the CSP access to our customer's subscriptions and Azure tenant is set up providing access via the AdminAgent/TenantAdmin group on the customer's subscription. I can only implicitly see them from our tenant or when I'm not explicitly in the customer's tenant. In other words they never show up in any lookups or dropdowns in our own Azure portal, I always have to state explicitly what tenant I want to access (portal.azure.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com [I am really fine with this BTW]).

Can anyone tell me how they are doing this? I mean there must be some way of doing this that scales?

These two articles were very helpful in understanding how the CSP model is intended to work. The second one is especially interesting as it provides a way of achieving what I want but I would prefer a way without adding my users to the customer’s Azure AD. Something like the delegate admin access that is provided by the AdminAgent/TenantAdmin groups.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloudbp/2016/06/08/identity-and-rights-management-in-csp-model/

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloudbp/2017/06/05/identity-and-rights-management-in-csp-model-part2/

But I feel there is so little info on this and where exactly is one supposed to look for help? I find being a CSP and looking for technical assistance not very comfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today you can't really use Azure AD Privileged Identity Management (PIM) through the CSP model, for the reason you've identified: individual users from a CSP partner are not represented in the customer's Azure AD tenant, so you can't assign a PIM policy to them.

My suggestion here would be to reduce to a bare minimum the number of users who have admin access to your customer's tenant, and use them only for inviting the rest of the users needed from your tenant into the customer's tenant as B2B guest users. Once they're in the tenant, they can be given access to the Azure subscription one normally would (and they can use PIM to get that access just-in-time).

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, you could implement an IAM system to make it easier to
create/delete accounts for each customer or partner's users in appropriate
containers in your Azure AD (or any other directory for that matter).

This is a solution designed to do exactly this kind of B2B delegated management:

https://hitachi-id.com/solutions/identity-express-b2b.html